# When is it possible to omit return type in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have the following function in Kotlin:

```
fun max(a: Int, b: Int): Int {
    return if (a > b) a else b
}
```

which could be simplified to:

```
fun max(a: Int, b: Int) = if (a > b) a else b
```

In the previous definition, the returned type of the function has been omitted, and this is known as *expression body*. I am wondering if there exists other cases in which it is possible to omit the return type of a function in Kotlin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions with block body must always specify return types explicitly, unless it's intended for them to return Unit.

If a function does not return any useful value, its return type is `Unit`. `Unit` is a type with only one value - Unit. This value does not have to be returned explicitly

```
fun printHello(name: String?): Unit {
    if (name != null)
        println("Hello ${name}")
    else
        println("Hi there!")
    // `return Unit` or `return` is optional
}
```

The `Unit` return type declaration is also optional. The above code is equivalent to

```
fun printHello(name: String?) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

when the return type is `Unit`

```
fun printHello(): Unit {
    print("hello")
}
```

is the same as

```
fun printHello() {
    print("hello")
}
```

also, is the same as

```
fun printHello() = print("hello")
```

Comment: what is `Unit` is it an equivalent of not returning a value?

Comment: Exactly, like void

Answer (score 1):

Usually, a function must declare it's return type. But if some functions consist of a single expression then we can omit the curly braces and the return type and uses the `=` symbol before the expression rather than the return keyword. This type of functions are called **Single Expression Functions**.

**Example:**

```
fun add(a: Int, b: Int): Int {
    return a + b
}
```

This code can be simplified to:

```
fun add(a: Int, b: Int) = a + b
```

The compiler will enforce you to do this.